# Java ME class access from another class

Tags: java-me, midp

`Java ME` main class runs very well. It has a `Form` with `CustomItem` (`Button` like shape). When it is clicked `keyPressed()` is called in the `CustomItem` class. But I need to get information from the main class in the `CustomItem` class. As the main class is already run hence I can't create new object of the main class in the `CustomItem`'s `keyPressed()` method. How to get access to the main class's element in the `keyPressed()` method?

Comment: can you please post the code?

Comment: @Lucifer, gnat Thanks for your help/attempt. But :| to who gave me negative. Was it that bad??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one thing, just pass the object of main class with your next class constructor when you calling that class. You can use your main class object for any purpose. Just pass it with your next class constructor. If you dont understand post code here i will tell you.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Sajid. You just got it and directed me to the right way.. :) I am glad.